# IICS, Unable to unpublish the TaskFlow using Rest API in POSTMAN

Tags: informatica-cloud, iics, informatica-data-integration-hub, iics-di

I am trying to 'unpublish' the Taskflow from POSTMAN, but it is failing with error message " javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException:RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: [https://usw5.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel/asset/v1/unpublish"](https://usw5.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel/asset/v1/unpublish%22)

Tried with both URLs, but unable to unpublish taskflow.

1. https://na1.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel/asset/v1/unpublish
2. https://usw5.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel/asset/v1/unpublish

Please find the Postman screenshot of request and response details:

[image]

Comment: Note the tag description on [tag:api] which says "DO NOT USE".